# Custom spring validator not being invoked

Tags: spring

I've created a custom constraint validator that works on a list of objects. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be getting invoked, it worked when I had a wrapper class containing the list with the annotation on the list.

This is the code that worked fine

```
public class wrapper {
    @ValidMyObjectList
    List<MyObject> myObjects;
    ...
}
```

But now I've got rid of the wrapper class and added the annotation to the parameter in the controller method.

Here's the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public List<MyObject> stopCheque(
      @ValidMyObjectList @RequestBody final List<MyObject> myObjects,
      final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

    ....
}
```

Here's the constraint annotation

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyObjectListValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface MyObjectList {

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  String message() default "";

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And part of the validator itself

```
public class MyObjectListValidator implements
    ConstraintValidator<MyObjectList, List<MyObject>> {


  @Override
  public void initialize(final MyObjectList myObjectList) {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(final List<MyObjectList> myObjectLists, final ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
    ...
}
```

Would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your Spring config class:

```
@Bean 
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
     return new MethodValidationPostProcessor(); 
}
```

and add @Validated to controller class.

Comment: I added the @Validated flag to my controller and it worked.Many thanks